# Array of a custom class as a property

Tags: class, delphi, components

I am trying to use an array of a custom class as a property for my component, but the problem is that the values are not been saved to the component, that means that if I set the values, save everything and open again the project, the values for the component disappears... My code looks like the following:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses  Windows, ExtCtrls,Classes,Controls;

type

  TMyClass=class(TPersistent)
  private
    FName: string;
    FValue: double;
  public
    property Name: string read FName write FName;
    property Value: double read FValue write FValue;
  end;

  TMyComponent= class(TCustomPanel)
  private
    FMyArray: array[0..200] of TMyClass;

    function GetmyArray(Index: Integer): TMyClass;

    procedure SetMyArray(index: Integer; Value: TMyClass);
  public
    property myArray[index: Integer]: TMyClass read GetMyArray write SetMyArray;
  end;

implementation

function TMyComponent.GetmyArray(Index: Integer): TMyClass;
begin
  result:= FmyArray[Index];
end;

procedure TMyComponent.SetMyArray(index: Integer; Value: TMyClass);
begin
  FMyArray[index].FName:= Value.FName;
  FMyArray[index].FValue:= Value.FValue;
end;

end.
```

I know that that only published properties can be streamed, but the problem is that my property is an array and it can not be published...
A suggestion that I had was to use `DefineProperties()` to provide a custom streaming but I don't see how to do this with an array.
Other possibility that I thought was to modify TMyClass to a kind of class that TMyComponent could be the parent of it, like it is done in TChart, which you can add different classes of series to it. But I don't know What class this should be

```
TMyClass=class(T???????????)
```

With that I could take out the property MyArray and create TMyClass and add to TMyComponent as the following:

```
MyArray1.parent:= MyComponent1;
MyArray2.parent:= MyComponent2;
...
```

. Which one is the better option? Or is there any other better idea?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The simpliest (and preferred) solution is to change `TMyClass` to derive from `TCollectionItem` and change `TMyComponent.FMyArray` to `TOwnedCollection`.  Then the DFM will stream the items automatically for you, and you gain native design-time support for creating and manipulating `TMyClass` objects and their properties.

Try this:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, ExtCtrls, Classes, Controls;

type
  TMyClass = class(TCollectionItem)
  private
    FName: string;
    FValue: double;

    procedure SetName(const AValue: string);
    procedure SetValue(AValue: double);
  public
    procedure Assign(ASource: TPersistent); override;
  published
    property Name: string read FName write SetName;
    property Value: double read FValue write SetValue;
  end;

  TMyArray = class(TOwnedCollection)
  private
    function  GetItem(Index: Integer): TMyClass;
    procedure SetItem(Index: Integer; const Value: TMyClass);
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TPersistent);
    function  Add: TMyClass; reintroduce;
    function  Insert(Index: Integer): TMyClass; reintroduce;
    property  Items[Index: Integer]: TMyClass read GetItem write SetItem; default;
  end;

  TMyComponent = class(TCustomPanel)
  private
    FMyArray: TMyArray;

    procedure SetMyArray(Value: TMyArray);
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
    destructor Destroy; override;
  published
    property myArray: TMyArray read FMyArray write SetMyArray;
  end;

implementation

procedure TMyClass.Assign(ASource: TPersistent);
begin
  if ASource is TMyClass then
  begin
    with TMyClass(ASource) do
    begin
      Self.FName := Name;
      Self.FValue := Value;
    end;
    Changed(False);
  end else
    inherited;
end;

procedure TMyClass.SetName(const AValue: string);
begin
  if FName <> AValue then
  begin
    FName := AValue;
    Changed(False);
  end;
end;

procedure TMyClass.SetValue(AValue: double);
begin
  if FValue <> AValue then
  begin
    FValue := AValue;
    Changed(False);
  end;
end;

constructor TMyArray.Create(AOwner: TPersistent);
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner, TMyClass);
end;

function TMyArray.GetItem(Index: Integer): TMyClass;
begin
  Result := TMyClass(inherited GetItem(Index));
end;

procedure TMyArray.SetItem(Index: Integer; const Value: TMyClass);
begin
  inherited SetItem(Index, Value);
end;

function TMyArray.Add: TMyClass;
begin
  Result := TMyClass(inherited Add);
end;

function TMyArray.Insert(Index: Integer): TMyClass;
begin
  Result := TMyClass(inherited Insert(Index));
end;

constructor TMyComponent.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited;
  FMyArray := TMyArray.Create(Self);
end;

destructor TMyComponent.Destroy;
begin
  FMyArray.Free;
  inherited;
end;

procedure TMyComponent.SetMyArray(Value: TMyArray);
begin
  FMyArray.Assign(Value);
end;

end.
```

Comment: I tested this version and it works fine, I just have to test in my real code which is a little bit more complex, thanks a lot

Comment: Was looking for the same thing. Great answer from Remy, thank you so much.

Answer (score 5):

I'd vote for DefineProperties! The necessary code might look like this (assuming none of the instances in the array is nil):

```
procedure TMyComponent.DefineProperties(Filer: TFiler);
begin
  inherited;
  Filer.DefineProperty('MyArray', ReadMyArray, WriteMyArray, true);
end;

procedure TMyComponent.ReadMyArray(Reader: TReader);
var
  N: Integer;
begin
  N := 0;
  Reader.ReadListBegin;
  while not Reader.EndOfList do begin
    Reader.ReadListBegin;
    FMyArray[N].Name := Reader.ReadString;
    FMyArray[N].Value := Reader.ReadFloat;
    Reader.ReadListEnd;
    Inc(N);
  end;
  Reader.ReadListEnd;
end;

procedure TMyComponent.WriteMyArray(Writer: TWriter);
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  Writer.WriteListBegin;
  for I := 0 to High(FMyArray) do begin
    Writer.WriteListBegin;
    Writer.WriteString(FMyArray[I].Name);
    Writer.WriteFloat(FMyArray[I].Value);
    Writer.WriteListEnd;
  end;
  Writer.WriteListEnd;
end;
```

Comment: I got an error:
[DCC Error] MyComponentTest1.pas(155): E2362 Cannot access protected symbol TReader.ReadProperty
And the same thing for WriteProperties

Comment: Indeed! I forgot that I had a class helper in scope that did the thing. Updated the answer.

Comment: Still didn't get my goal.. I check the form as text and I got that:
  `object MyComponent1: TMyComponent
    Left = 160
    Top = 181
    Width = 185
    Height = 41
    MyArray = (
      ())`

Comment: Did you declare DefineProperties as override?

Comment: yes and also `procedure TMyComponent.DefineProperties(Filer: TFiler);
begin
  inherited DefineProperties(Filer);
  Filer.DefineProperty('MyArray', ReadMyArray, WriteMyArray, true);
end;`

Comment: Found it: the properties of TMyClass have to be published to work with the streaming system.

Comment: I changed it, and I am still getting an empty thing: MyArray = ( ())

Comment: Changed the code to avoid calls to ReadProperty and WriteProperties.

Comment: Nothing, should I not read for example FMyArray[N].Name instead of only FMyArray?