# Delphi - Add a Buttons property to component

Tags: delphi, button, components

I am making a Delphi DB aware component and i need to add a 'buttons' property, which should show with the ... button in the object inspector and after clicking the ... button a list should be shown to see the defined buttons, add, delete button definitions, i only know basics on component design and i'm puzzled on how to make this work.

The buttons definition of course has to be saved in the dfm file.
I have been reading the question in this thread:
[How can I make a TList property from my custom control streamable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37500480/how-can-i-make-a-tlist-property-from-my-custom-control-streamable) but the 'fItems:=TCollection.Create' statement in the constructor won't compile (error E2029 '(' expected but ')' found')

Does anyone see what i am doing wrong and/or can anyone provide a example of how to make a dynamic list of buttons in the component?

```
type
TAlignment = (Horizontal, Vertical);

TButtonsItem = class (TCollectionItem)
private
    FButton: TcxButton;
published
    property Button: TcxButton read FButton write FButton;
end;

TButtonsItemClass = class of TButtonsItem;

TFlexButtonGroupBox = class(TcxGroupBox)
private
    FDataLink: TFieldDataLink;
    FAbout: string;
    fAlignment: TAlignment;
    fEnabled: Boolean;
    fButtons: TCollection;
    procedure SetAlignment(const Value: TAlignment);
    function GetDataField: string;
    function GetDataSource: TdataSource;
    procedure SetDataField(const Value: string);
    procedure SetDataSource(const Value: TdataSource);
    procedure DataChange(Sender: TObject);
    procedure SetEnabled(const Value: Boolean);
protected
public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
    destructor Destroy; override;
published
    property DataField: string read GetDataField write SetDataField;
    property DataSource: TdataSource read GetDataSource write SetDataSource;
    property Enabled: Boolean read fEnabled write SetEnabled;
    property About: string read FAbout write FAbout;
    property Buttons: TCollection read fButtons write fButtons;
    property Alignment: TAlignment read fAlignment write SetAlignment;
end;
```

In constructor:

```
fButtons := TCollection.Create(TButtonsItemClass); <- error
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you looked at the source of TDBNavigator?

Comment: I will take a look at that, it is not exactly what i was looking for since TDBNavigator has a static number of created buttons and no real buttons published property where users can dynamically add/delete/edit buttons.

There must be another vcl component which does that i can examine i suppose.

Comment: Well, the Columns property of  TDBGrid is a descendant of TCollectionItem.

Comment: Did you try reading the [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Berlin/en/System.Classes.TCollection), especially the two **Note** entries at the bottom, and particularly the second of those notes? There are also a list of several VCL components that use collections for their items, which can give you any number of examples to look at to help you.

Comment: I am looking at components and learning, thanks for the tips.

Comment: I am looking at components and learning, thanks for the tips.I can't spend much time on the component now, u know, it being christmas and all, i also have the Danny Thorpe book coming in a few weeks so i hope that will make it clearer for me.I have the object inspector property workign now but have yet to find out how to 'trap' the adding/deleting/editing of a item so i can create the buttons in the events.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Franky, sorry nobody has explained the problem yet. I do agree that the compiler error

```
[dcc32 Error] Unit2.pas(26): E2029 '(' expected but ')' found
```

is not good enough to understand the problem. Actually you are using incompatible types in your create statement. The compiler needs a **value**(variable) of TButtonsItemClass but you are using a **type** there. To resolve the compiler error you should use

```
var
  LItemClass: TButtonsItemClass;
...
  LItemClass := TButtonsItem;
  fButtons := TCollection.Create(LItemClass);
```

or in short

```
fButtons := TCollection.Create(TButtonsItem);
```

PS I should also point out that your code may have another potential problem (button property of TButtonsItem class). I would assume that it is a reference to another component and I would expect that you will use FreeNotification for it.

Comment: Thanks Max, i had already solved it by reading this url: http://www.atug.com/andypatterns/collections.htm#TCollectionMerits (which is from the Danny Thorpe book i assume).I am now facing 2 other issues i have no idea on, do i create new questions for those or is it custom on stackoverflow to add additional questions in the same thread?

Comment: I think it is better to create new thread, but you could always refer all the connected threads in your question so everybody could understand the context quickly

Comment: Thanks Max, yes i already have a new thread about the other questions and it's already been answered...now only one more thing to figure out...looking for a solution online but if i can't find it i'll make another thread for that.