# TObjectList<myclass> field into a class is not saved

Tags: delphi

I have a class that contains a `TObjectList<T>` list of objects of another class.

```
TMyElementClass = class (TPersistent)
private
  ....
public
  ....
end;

TMyElemContainerClass = class (TPersistent)
private
  fElemList: TObjectList<TMyElementClass>;
  ...
published
  ElemList: TObjectList<TMyElementClass> read fElemList write fElemList;
end;

var
  Elements: TMyElemContainerClass;
```

I register both classes:

```
   System.Classes.RegisterClass (TMyElemContainerClass);
   System.Classes.RegisterClass (TMyElementClass);
```

The problem is, when the `Elements` object is "saved" to a stream, all of the published fields are correctly saved, but the list itself isn't.

What's wrong?

Comment: TObjectList is not descended from TPersistent?

Comment: Please show real code. Your example wont compile and we can't know if you are creating your object list, for example, so we need, at a minimum, your constructors.

Comment: Your expectations are set too high

Comment: `write fElemList` - this part is so wrong and utterly toxic that I can not even start to explain... Look at VCL sources. It always is done as a procedure *copying the content* from one object to another, but never just leaking old object and creating another pointer to new object, as your code. For example `Label1.Font := MyFont` is executed as `Label1.Font.Assign(MyFont)` copying the content but never interfering with lifetime management of any of two font objects.

Comment: @Dsm `TObjectList<X>` and `TList<X>` are standard Delphi classes since 2009 edition (practically usable only since 2010 edition at least)

Answer (score 2):

`TObjectList` is not a streamable class.  Just because you use it in a  `published` property doesn't mean the streaming system automatically knows how to stream it.  If you are using the DFM streaming system, only classes that derive from `TPersistent` are streamable, but `TObjectList` does not.  You will have to implement custom streaming logic for it.

Consider changing your design to use `TCollection` and `TCollectionItem` instead, eg:

```
TMyElementClass = class (TCollectionItem)
private
  ...
public
  ...
published
  ...
end;

TMyElemCollectionClass = class (TCollection)
private
  function GetElem(Index: Integer): TMyElementClass;
  procedure SetElem(Index: Integer; Value: TMyElementClass);
public
  constructor Create; reintroduce;
  function Add: TMyElementClass; reintroduce;
  function Insert(Index: Integer): TMyElementClass; reintroduce;
  property Elements[Index: Integer]: TMyElementClass read GetElem write SetElem; default;
end;

TMyElemContainerClass = class (TPersistent)
private
  fElemList: TMyElemCollectionClass;
  procedure SetElemList(Value: TMyElemCollectionClass);
  ...
public
  constructor Create;
  destructor Destroy; override;
  ...
published
  ElemList: TMyElemCollectionClass read fElemList write SetElemList;
end;

...

constructor TMyElemCollectionClass.Create;
begin
  inherited Create(TMyElementClass);
end;

function TMyElemCollectionClass.GetElem(Index: Integer): TMyElementClass;
begin
  Result := TMyElementClass(inherited GetItem(Index));
end;

procedure TMyElemCollectionClass.SetElem(Index: Integer; Value: TMyElementClass);
begin
  inherited SetItem(Index, Value);
end;

function TMyElemCollectionClass.Add: TMyElementClass;
begin
  Result := TMyElementClass(inherited Add);
end;

function TMyElemCollectionClass.Insert(Index: Integer): TMyElementClass;
begin
  Result := TMyElementClass(inherited Insert(Index));
end;

constructor TMyElemContainerClass.Create;
begin
  inherited;
  fElemList := TMyElemCollectionClass.Create;
end;

destructor TMyElemContainerClass.Destroy;
begin
  fElemList.Destroy;
  inherited;
end;

procedure TMyElemContainerClass.SetElemList(Value: TMyElemCollectionClass);
begin
  fElemList.Assign(Value);
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

Remy gave you one avenue to try.

Another possible way would be implement this list streaming manually.

You would have to

1. derive your `TMyElemContainerClass` from `TComponent`
2. remove `ElemList` from `published` properties
3. override `DefineProperties` method that would declare some virtual, not-existing published property to be streamed in and out. You may even name it `ElemList` or by any other identifier you would see fit. It would be used by Delphi instead your `TObjectList` object.
4. implement stream-oriented reader and writer methods for the said virtual property, they should iterate through all the items and save/load them.

Explore documentation from here: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Berlin/en/System.Classes.TComponent.DefineProperties

See one of many (and there really are many) examples (using arrays rather than lists, but the idea is the same) at [How to use DefineProperties in a custom Class Object for Arrays - Delphi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20662975/how-to-use-defineproperties-in-a-custom-class-object-for-arrays-delphi)